# "variable namespace is undeclared" error in Polymer

Tags: polymer-1.0

I am trying to create a new helper file in a Polymer project.

helper.html looks like this:

```html
<script src="helper.ts"></script>
```

Helper looks like this:

```
namespace my_namespace {
  export function foo(){}
}
```

I get several errors including "variable namespace is undeclared", "Parse error. Semi-colon expected", "variable missing_expression is undeclared", "Parse error. primary expression expected".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check for these things:

1. Your namespace must match the name field in your `tf_web_library` declaration in your BUILD file
2. Add both your helper.html and helper.js files to your BUILD file.
3. In helper.html, the `src` field should be helper**.js** not helper**.ts**